# Outline boundary of a union of two curvilinear areas in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Found several questions here obviously related to what I want, [TikZ outline stroke of a compound shape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269131/48166), [How to outline the union of an annulus and a rectangle in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/587298/48166), [TikZ: Drawing an arc from an intersection to an intersection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238967/48166) and some others, but still could not figure out how to adapt them for my needs.

I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-4,-1) rectangle (4,3);
\coordinate (a) at (-4,-3);
\coordinate (va) at (3,7.5);
\shadedraw[name path=higher,opacity=.3] (a) .. controls ($(a)+(va)$) .. ($(a)+(6,0)$);
\coordinate (b) at (4,-5);
\coordinate (vb) at (-3,7.5);
\shadedraw[name path=lower,opacity=.3] ($(b)-(6,0)$) .. controls ($(b)+(vb)$) .. (b);
\path [name intersections={of=higher and lower,by=x}];
\coordinate (xa) at (-1.65,3.45);
\coordinate (xb) at (1,.75);
\draw[thick] (a) .. controls ($(a)+.89*(va)$) and ($(x)+(xa)$) .. (x)
                 .. controls ($(x)+(xb)$) and ($(b)+.6*(vb)$) .. (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

but it took me quite some effort to find, by blind trial-and-error, the six decimals in the code, and, if you look attentively, the picture is still not entirely accurate.

Is there a better way to draw that thick line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be achieved by use of the [spath3](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library (this *ought* to work with the current version on CTAN but if not the latest version is available from [github](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3) - it's just waiting for me to upload it to CTAN).

After drawing and shading the original paths, it splits then at the point where they intersect.  Individual components can then be rendered separately, and also welded together to form a nice joint at the intersection point.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598243/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  calc,
  intersections,
  spath3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-4,-1) rectangle (4,3);
\coordinate (a) at (-4,-3);
\coordinate (va) at (3,7.5);
\shadedraw[spath/save=higher,opacity=.3] (a) .. controls ($(a)+(va)$) .. ($(a)+(6,0)$);
\coordinate (b) at (4,-5);
\coordinate (vb) at (-3,7.5);
\shadedraw[spath/save=lower,opacity=.3] ($(b)-(6,0)$) .. controls ($(b)+(vb)$) .. (b);

\tikzset{
  spath/split at intersections={higher}{lower},
  spath/get components of={higher}\higherPath,
  spath/get components of={lower}\lowerPath,
}

\draw[
  thick,
  spath/use=\getComponentOf\higherPath{1},
  spath/use={\getComponentOf\lowerPath{2},weld},
];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

End result:

[image: Outlined shape]

Detail of the intersection:

[image: Detail of intersection point]

Comment: Great work! I wish I could accept both answers - yours for universality and the other one for minimality...

Comment: Version 2.4 (Feb 23 2021) from MiKTeX package repositories works perfectly with the latest system files (pgf 3.1.9a in particular) on Windows 10

Comment: One question: what does `weld` do?

Comment: I've always felt it a strength of the users of this site that although there can only be _one_ accepted answer then the value of other contributions is acknowledged, so I wouldn't worry overmuch about which is marked as "accepted".

Comment: `weld` is what produces the nice join.  When an `spath` is `use`d then there are a variety of options for how it combines with whatever is already there.  Using the `weld` option makes it into a contiguous path.  Without that it would be two separate components.  It's the difference between `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1);` and `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) (1,0) -- (1,1);`

Comment: @AndrewStacey spath3 is really powerful now, impressive.

Comment: @kpym thanks! I got the chance to do some work on it earlier in the year and I'm quite pleased with how it's turning out.

Answer (score 7):

One simple way of doing this is to clip out the portion below node (x). Store your two curves to be able to use them twice, one for the shading, and one for the line drawing.
[image: outline of two curves]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (-4,-1) rectangle (4,3);
        \coordinate (a) at (-4,-3);
        \coordinate (va) at (3,7.5);
        \coordinate (b) at (4,-5);
        \coordinate (vb) at (-3,7.5);
        
        \def\higherpath{(a) .. controls ($(a)+(va)$) .. ($(a)+(6,0)$)}
        \def\lowerpath{($(b)-(6,0)$) .. controls ($(b)+(vb)$) .. (b)}
                
        \shadedraw[name path=higher,opacity=.3] \higherpath;
        \shadedraw[name path=lower,opacity=.3] \lowerpath;
        
        \path [name intersections={of=higher and lower,by=x}];
                
        \clip (-4,-1) -- (-2,-1) -- (x) -- (2,-1) -- (3,-1) -- (3,3) -| cycle;
        \draw \higherpath \lowerpath;
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very smart! Still needs to do something "by hand" but it is a joke compared to what I've been through.

Comment: I am really sorry I had to accept another one, as more systematic and automated. I believe your solution would in one or other form work in 99% of the cases. I wish it would be possible to accept two different answers as useful in different situations.

Comment: Don't worry about that. You have to accept the answer you find the best, and Andrew's one is better, since it provides a *really continuous* path instead of masking the part you don't want. I'm not that familiar with the `spath3` library of his, and sure I'll have to dig in because it's wonderful.