# Outlining the boundary of a shape defined by intersections in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to place a thick border around the white area in the image below, while also maintaining the dashed lines in the gray regions. Is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

My code can be found below. Thanks!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\clip (-4.5,-4) rectangle (4.5,4);
\filldraw[fill=white](-4.5,-4) rectangle (4.5,4);

\fill[fill=gray!50] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
\fill[fill=gray!50] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
\fill[fill=gray!50] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
\fill[fill=gray!50] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);
\fill[fill=gray!50] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);

\draw[dashed] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
\draw[dashed] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
\draw[dashed] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
\draw[dashed] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);
\draw[dashed] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

**UPDATE:**

Using the method suggested in [Q238967](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238967/tikz-drawing-an-arc-from-an-intersection-to-an-intersection), I've been able to get close, but I am having an issue with one of the lines. I've added the updated code below, along with the new image.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \clip (-4.5,-4) rectangle (4.5,4);
    \filldraw[fill=white](-4.5,-4) rectangle (4.5,4);

    \fill[fill=gray!50] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);    
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);


    \draw[name path=one, dashed] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
    \draw[name path=two, dashed] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
    \draw[name path = three, dashed] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
    \draw[name path = four, dashed] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);
    \draw[name path = five, dashed] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);


    \path[name path = temp1, red, intersection segments={of=one and two,sequence=R2}];
    \draw[red,ultra thick, intersection segments={of=temp1 and three,sequence=L3}];
    
    \path[name path = temp2, red, intersection segments={of=one and five,sequence=L1}];
    \draw[red,ultra thick, intersection segments={of=temp2 and two,sequence=L3}];

    \path[name path = temp3, red, intersection segments={of=four and five,sequence=L3}];
    \draw[red,ultra thick, intersection segments={of=temp3 and three, sequence=L1}];

    \path[name path = temp4, red, intersection segments={of=three and four,sequence=L1}];
    \draw[red,ultra thick, intersection segments={of=temp4 and two, sequence=L1}];

    \path[name path = temp5, red, intersection segments={of=one and five,sequence=R3}];
    \draw[red,ultra thick, intersection segments={of=temp5 and four, sequence=L1}];


\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Unrelated to your problem but TikZ has polar coordinates: `(<angle>:<radius>)`. So instead of `({(2 + 5)*cos(115)},{(2 + 5)*sin(115)})` you can simply use `(115 : 2 + 5)`.

Comment: This can be solved by determining the intersections of the circles (which you can do either mathematically or by using the `intersections` library) and then redraw the arcs that lie on the circles (needs a bit more math), by using the `spath3` library that can split and join paths at their intersections. The `pgfplots` package's `fillbetween` library can do the same with a very different syntax. [Q238967](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238967), [Q71548](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71548) and many related Q&As come to mind.

Comment: That said, do you really want a white border around the middle region or do you want the circles to not be drawn/dashed when they touch the middle region? Mathematically the same problem but maybe semantically more correct … (and I could think of a very easy slightly dirty solution for it).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm trying to draw a thick black outline around the inner white region.

Comment: Could you edit your post with a complete working code, starting by `\documentclass` and ending by `\end{document}`? This way, it would be easier to help you out.

Comment: Both answers to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598243/48166) might be used to actually automate finding the curve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The left circle is indeed a trouble maker since internally it is still an arc starting at angle 0 going all around. This will lead to additional segmentations.

Here is my take on this by doing the dashed parts as arcs that are constructed so that this segmentation won't happen. By choosing a tight angle we also only have exactly one intersection point between each pair of circles (now arcs).

With `fillbetween` I don't see a good solution to have one path with no move to between the segments which is why I'm using `line cap = round` here to hide that fact. There's [`inner moveto`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-fillbetween#sec-46.5) (which actually seems to be in the `/pgf/fill between/` name space) but I don't know how this should be used. The example doesn't even use it.

This is why I provide a `spath3` solutions.

After we just `split at intersections` each pair of path and then remove the first and the third/last segment on each path we are left with five path segments we just need to connect.

In contrast to the `fillbetween` solution we can actually join the parts so that it will be one continous path. Not only do the joins look good now we can use the whole area that the path contains to fill, shade or pattern it properly.

---

Keep in mind that all circles and arcs are constructed counterclockwise and your circles are enumerated in the same manner. However, this means we have to construct the inner area clockwise which is why the final `\draw` in both solutions go 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.

And yes, I start counting at `0` because it makes it easier to do modulo operations on the paths (as the `spath3` solutions shows).

### Code (`fillbetween`)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-4.5,-4) rectangle (4.5,4);

\foreach \ang/\rad in {45/8, 115/5, 180/10, 270/9, 345/7}
  \fill[gray!50] (\ang:2+\rad) circle[radius=\rad];

\tikzset{
  arc path/.code args={#1/#2/#3}{% ungrouped loop
    \draw[dashed, name path=p#1] ([shift=(#2+135:#3)]#2:2+#3)
      arc[start angle=#2+135, delta angle=90, radius=#3];},
  arc path/.list={0/45/8, 1/115/5, 2/180/10, 3/270/9, 4/345/7},
  split paths/.code 2 args={
    \path[intersection segments={of=p#1 and p#2, sequence=R1}, name path=p#2 on p#1];},
  split paths/.list={01, 12, 23, 34, 40}
}
\draw[ultra thick, line cap=round,
  intersection segments/.list={{of=p4 and p3 on p2, sequence=R2},
                               {of=p3 and p2 on p1, sequence=R2},
                               {of=p2 and p1 on p0, sequence=R2},
                               {of=p1 and p0 on p4, sequence=R2},
                               {of=p0 and p4 on p3, sequence=R2}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code (`spath3`)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3, intersections}
\newcommand*\NextOf[2]{\pgfintmod{#1+1}{#2}}
%\newcommand*\PrevOf[2]{\pgfintmod{#1-1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-4.5,-4) rectangle (4.5,4);

\foreach \ang/\rad in {45/8, 115/5, 180/10, 270/9, 345/7}
  \fill[gray!50] (\ang:2+\rad) circle[radius=\rad];

\tikzset{
  arc path/.code args={#1/#2/#3}{% ungrouped loop
    \draw[dashed, spath/save=p#1] ([shift=(#2+135:#3)]#2:2+#3)
      arc[start angle=#2+135, delta angle=90, radius=#3];},
  arc path/.list={0/45/8, 1/115/5, 2/180/10, 3/270/9, 4/345/7},
  split paths/.style={spath/split at intersections={p#1}{p\NextOf{#1}{5}}},
  split paths/.list={0, ..., 4},
  remove start and end/.style={spath/remove components={p#1}{1, 3}},
  remove start and end/.list={0, ..., 4},
}
\draw[
  line width=1ex,
  spath/append no move/.list={p4, p..., p0},
  spath/adjust and close=current];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (`spath3`)

[image]

[Not clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8gbB.png)

Comment: Obviously, since a good portion of the diagram is clipped away we can get away very easily by doing this with arcs. If we didn't clip it we could just draw the dashed lines normally and still construct the arcs (but not draw them). Alternative, we can draw the circles as arcs that go fully around but start somewhere outside our point of interest. (However, then we have to keep in mind that two circles can intersect at two points.)

Comment: That's a really neat solution.  I particularly like the way you've condensed the code by rotating the circles so that each circle can be treated in the same way.

Answer (score 9):

You could also do this using the handy `buildcycle` macro in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), but you need to be careful about how you construct the circles.  In particular you need to make sure that you rotate them so that none of the `point 0` points lies inside any of the other circles.  Purely for comparison, here is my effort:

[image]

Compile this with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
path C[];
C1 = fullcircle scaled 300 rotated 115 shifted 210 dir 115;
C2 = fullcircle scaled 480 rotated  45 shifted 300 dir 45;
C3 = fullcircle scaled 420 rotated 345 shifted 270 dir 345;
C4 = fullcircle scaled 540 rotated 270 shifted 330 dir 270;
C5 = fullcircle scaled 600 rotated 180 shifted 360 dir 180;

path S; S = unitsquare shifted -(1/2,1/2) scaled 300;
for i = 1 upto 5:
  C[i] := C[i] cutbefore S cutafter S;
endfor

path P; P = buildcycle(C1, C2, C3, C4, C5);

beginfig(1);
  fill S withcolor 7/8;
  fill P withcolor 7/8[red, white];
  draw S;
  draw P withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor 2/3 red;
  for i=1 upto 5: 
    draw C[i] dashed evenly; 
  endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

If you want the red line to hide the dashed lines, then move the `draw P` line after the loop that draws the arcs.  And you might not want any of the colour anyway, so something like this might be better:

```
beginfig(1);
  fill S withcolor 7/8;
  fill P withcolor background;
  draw S;
  for i=1 upto 5: 
    draw C[i] dashed evenly; 
  endfor
  draw P withpen pencircle scaled 1;
endfig;
```

which would give:

[image]

### Notes

- the units are PostScript points 28.35 = 1cm
- you can do polar coordinates in MP using the macro `dir`.  The expression `dir 100` expands to `right rotated 100` and so gives you the `<pair>` value `(sind 100, cosd 100)` which will lie on the unit circle.  The expression `200 dir 100` scales this point to be the polar coordinate with radius 200bp and angle 100°.
- this works best if you use the default units (PostScript points) because you can write `200 dir 45` directly.  You *can* use `cm` etc, but you have to write `7 cm * dir 45` which is a bit less elegant.
- Note that in this idiom `fullcircle scaled 300 rotated 115 shifted 210 dir 115;` the numbers represent points, degrees, points, and degrees, respectively.

Comment: Ah, so the problem with the OP's code is that the starting point of the circle is due east of its centre, so the left-hand curve doesn't capture the whole of the intended path. I *think* that `spath3` gets this right, but I'd have to check to be sure.

Comment: Oh, how nice. I just had to make sure I can do what I know in TiKz. And I can ! Here in metapost I can also insert the text, for example `labeloffset:=7bp;  label.top(btex $M$ etex, point 1 of P);` or `label.rt(btex $M$ etex, point 7.2 of P);`.

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with the `spath` package but just for fun and free time

An answer extrapolated from the one given by @AndrewStacy --

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/682553/197451

The originator can please advise

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections, fillbetween, spath3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    \filldraw[fill=white](-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
    
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
    \draw[spath/save=circle8, dashed] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
    
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
    \draw[spath/save=circle5, dashed] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
    
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
    \draw[spath/save=circle10, dashed] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
    
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);    
    \draw[spath/save=circle9, dashed] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);
    
    \fill[fill=gray!50] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);
    \draw[spath/save=circle7, dashed] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);
%   
\tikzset{%
  spath/split at intersections={circle8}{circle5},
    spath/split at intersections={circle5}{circle10},
        spath/split at intersections={circle10}{circle9},
            spath/split at intersections={circle9}{circle7},
                spath/split at intersections={circle7}{circle8},
  spath/get components of={circle8}\cptsA,
    spath/get components of={circle5}\cptsB,
        spath/get components of={circle10}\cptsC,
            spath/get components of={circle9}\cptsD,
                spath/get components of={circle7}\cptsE,
                    spath/get components of={circle8}\cptsF,
}

\draw[
red,
thick,
spath/use=\getComponentOf{\cptsA}{-2},
spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsB}{-3}},
spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsC}{-2}},
spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsD}{-2}},
spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsE}{-2}},
spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsF}{3}},
];
%   
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**output**

[image]

**EDIT**

Based on the comments @AndrewStacey to get all the dashed lines visible also

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections, fillbetween, spath3}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        \filldraw[fill=white](-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
        
        \fill[fill=gray!50] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
            \fill[fill=gray!50] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
                \fill[fill=gray!50] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
                        \fill[fill=gray!50] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);    
                                \fill[fill=gray!50] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);
                
        \draw[spath/save=circle8, dashed] (45 : 2 + 8) circle (8);
            \draw[spath/save=circle5, dashed] (115 : 2 + 5) circle (5);
                \draw[spath/save=circle10, dashed] (180 : 2 + 10) circle (10);
                    \draw[spath/save=circle9, dashed] (270 : 2 + 9) circle (9);
                        \draw[spath/save=circle7, dashed] (345 : 2 + 7) circle (7);
        %   
        \tikzset{%
            spath/split at intersections={circle8}{circle5},
            spath/split at intersections={circle5}{circle10},
            spath/split at intersections={circle10}{circle9},
            spath/split at intersections={circle9}{circle7},
            spath/split at intersections={circle7}{circle8},
            spath/get components of={circle8}\cptsA,
            spath/get components of={circle5}\cptsB,
            spath/get components of={circle10}\cptsC,
            spath/get components of={circle9}\cptsD,
            spath/get components of={circle7}\cptsE,
            spath/get components of={circle8}\cptsF,
        }
        
        \draw[
        blue,
        thick,
        spath/use=\getComponentOf{\cptsA}{-2},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsB}{-3}},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsC}{-2}},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsD}{-2}},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsE}{-2}},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf{\cptsF}{3}},
        ];
        %   
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Looks great!  If you reorder the initial commands so that all the fills are first and the dashed-draws after then you'll get all the dashed lines on top.