# Intersection between tangent and circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, tangent

I am trying to define the tangent line of a circle at a given azimuth then use this intersection to define segment. The MWE here shows that intersection seems badly computed using `[turn]90:` command to draw the tangent because it create some random intersections with the circle. Thus, I cannot fill the area defined by the intersection of tangents and circle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc,positioning,quotes,fillbetween}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\R{1}
    \def\angle{30}
    \draw[name path=C,blue] circle[radius=\R];
    \node at (60:\R) {\tiny Fill here};
    \draw[name path=L,green] (30:\R) -- ([turn]90:\R) ;
    \draw[name path=L2,yellow] (90:\R) -- ([turn]-90:\R) ;
    \draw[red,ultra thick,intersection segments={of=L and C,
         sequence={B1}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with full problem**

I need to fill the area between 2 circles and 2 tangents of internal circle. I used to use `intersection segments` to compute the intersection of circles and lines but as far as the `intersections` library have erronous intersection computation with tangent lines, I didn't manage to create such picture without code duplication. Here is an example based on @Qrrbrbirlbel solution but the filled area has to be reduced by computed intersections of the second circle and tangents.
Also, I need to draw the internal `arc` with a different color than other lines.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\RA{1} \def\RB{2} \def\angleA{75} \def\angleB{-65}
    \filldraw[red,fill opacity=0.3] (\angleA:\RA) coordinate (start)
      arc[start angle=\angleA, end angle=\angleB, radius=\RA] coordinate[at end] (end)
      -- (intersection of start--{$(start)+(\angleA+90:\RB)$}
                        and end--{$(end)  +(\angleB-90:\RB)$})
      -- cycle;
    \draw[red,overlay] (\angleA:\RB) arc[start angle=\angleA, end angle=\angleB, radius=\RB]; % this should limit the fill area and be drawn in red
    \draw[green] (start) arc[start angle=\angleA, end angle=\angleB, radius=\RA]; % this is because I need this segment to be in green
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify: "Any idea of how I can split the circle correctly, meaning in the present case that the red segment show go up to 360°?" with more text or an image of the desired result?

Comment: @dexteritas In fact, my question was not clear. Is it better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `intersections` library (which is used by both `fillbetween` and `spath3`) finds two intersection points between the circle and the green line:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=C]circle[radius=1];
\draw[name path=L](30:1) -- ([turn]90:1);
\path[name intersections={of=C and L, total=\t}]
  node foreach \i in {1, ..., \t} at (intersection-\i) {x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This messes everything up.

In this case, you don't really need `fillbetween`. You know the angles (30° and 60°) and the intersection [between straight lines can be found via the undocumented `intersection of` syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309382/16595) without any extra library. Though, you could also use `intersections` here.

I'm using the `calc` library for a shorter syntax

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{1} \def\angle{30}

\fill[red] (\angle:\R) coordinate (start)
  arc[start angle=\angle, end angle=90, radius=\R] coordinate[at end] (end)
  -- (intersection of start--{$(start)+(\angle+90:1)$} and end--{$(end)+(0:1)$})
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{1} \def\angleA{75} \def\angleB{-75}

\fill[red] (\angleA:\R) coordinate (start)
  arc[start angle=\angleA, end angle=\angleB, radius=\R] coordinate[at end] (end)
  -- (intersection of start--{$(start)+(\angleA+90:1)$}
                    and end--{$(end)  +(\angleB-90:1)$})
  -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

---

For your updated problem, I've tried with `fillbetween` – it didn't work, so here's a `spath3` solution.

Instead of specifying which segments you want between the intersection of two paths, the approach is kind of the opposite:

1. Split the paths at their intersections.
2. Remove the parts we don't want.
3. Concatenate the paths in the proper order and direction.

In a [recent answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694528) I provide (almost) the same picture once with `fillbetween` and once with `spath3`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, spath3, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spath/save/.append style=overlay]
\def\RA{1} \def\RB{2} \def\angleA{-60} \def\angleB{85}

\path[spath/save=RA] (\angleA:\RA) coordinate (start)
  arc[start angle=\angleA, end angle=\angleB, radius=\RA] coordinate[at end] (end)
  -- (intersection of start--{$(start)+(\angleA+90:1)$}
                    and end--{$(end)  +(\angleB-90:1)$})
  -- cycle;
\path[spath/save=RB]
  (\angleA:\RB) arc[start angle=\angleA, end angle=\angleB, radius=\RB];

\fill[
  red, spath/.cd,
  split at intersections={RA}{RB},
  remove components={RB}{1, 3},
  remove components={RA}{1},
  use=RB,
  append reverse no move=RA];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I didn't knew the `intersection of` syntax!
I know that was not my initial question, but as far as I simplified my real problem to have this kind of answer, your solution make my real solution a bit complicated. Actually, I need to fill an area between 2 circles of radius `RA` and `RB` and the two tangent you've drawn on the second picture. I've manage to do so with `intersection segments` but with code duplication. Any idea of how to solve my updated problem?

Comment: @Sigmun Here, I'd mix the already given solution with the usual find-intersection-and-build-new-paths approach. However, I couldn't get the proper segment with `fillbetween` which is why I've opted for a `spath3` aproach.

Comment: Thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel