Filling between two paths (using intersections)
I've been playing with sketching plots using tikz's \draw plot command, rather than using pgfplots (mainly as these are quick-and-dirty notes for students, rather than anything mission-critical). It's working well, but I've not yet been able to work out how to fill between two paths where tikz is working out the intersections.
MWE:
\documentclass [border = 5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [<->] (-3, 0) -- (5, 0) node [below] {$x$};
        \draw [<->] (0, -1) -- (0, 4) node [right] {$y$};
        \draw [name path = gx] plot [domain = -2:4] (\x, {0.25 * (\x - 1) * (\x  - 1) + 1.2}) node [above] {$g(x)$};
        \draw [name path = fx] plot [domain = -1.1:2.5] (\x * 2, {0.8 * (\x + 1) * (\x - 1) * (\x - 2) + 1}) node [below right] {$f(x)$};
        \draw [name intersections = {of = fx and gx}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-1 |- {{(0, 0)}}) node [below] {$a$} (intersection-2) -- (intersection-2|- {{(0, 0)}}) node [below] {$b$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This works brilliantly for what I want, but I'd now like to shade the area enclosed by f(x) and g(x), between x = a and x = b. I've done this successfully for other graphs I've draw, but I've done this by actually knowing the intersection points and simply drawing around the hole I want filled. Because I've changed the scales of the two graphs (to make it fit better on the page), I'd rather just "use the intersections" rather than having to calculate them any time I want to fill in.
Any guidance or pointers to what I should be looking for would be gratefully received. (I'd rather not have to load other libraries if at all possible, but if that's what's needed let me know).

Take a look at pgfplotsand \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} p. 105 in the documentation.

The spath3 TikZ library can do this.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694528/86 is probably one of the best similar questions to look at for an example.

With the math library to find the abscissa of the intersection points and an expl3 command.
You have to reverse the reading direction in the domain to avoid crossing. domain[#1:#2] for one and domain[#2:#1] for the other.
\documentclass [border = 5mm] {standalone}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/724056/filling-between-two-paths-using-intersections
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary {math}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\area}{m m O{red}}{   
  \fill[#3]
  plot[
    domain= \dim_to_decimal_in_cm:n {#1} \c_colon_str 
            \dim_to_decimal_in_cm:n {#2},samples=129]
            (\x,{g(\x)})--
  plot [
    domain =  0.5*\dim_to_decimal_in_cm:n {#2}\c_colon_str
              0.5*\dim_to_decimal_in_cm:n {#1},samples=129]
            (2*\x,{f(\x)}) -- cycle;
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tikzset
{
  declare function=
  {
      f(\x)= 0.8 * (\x + 1) * (\x - 1) * (\x - 2) + 1; % function
      g(\x)=0.25 * (\x - 1) * (\x  - 1) + 1.2;                    % 
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [<->] (-3, 0) -- (5, 0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw [<->] (0, -1) -- (0, 4) node [right] {$y$};      
    \draw [thick,name path = gx] plot [domain = -2:4,samples=129] (\x, {g(\x)}) node [above] {$g(x)$};
    \draw [thick,name path = fx] plot [domain = -1.1:2.5,samples=129] (2*\x,{f(\x)}) node [below right] {$f(x)$};
    \draw [name intersections = {of = fx and gx}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-1 |- {{(0, 0)}}) node [below](a) {$a$} (intersection-2) -- (intersection-2|- {{(0, 0)}}) node [below](b) {$b$};
    \tikzmath{
      coordinate \c;
      \c1 = (intersection-1);
      \c2 = (intersection-2);
      }
    \area{\cx1}{\cx2}
    \area{50pt}{60pt}[blue]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This was very helpful, thanks. I pared back the code to what I needed, and manually did the conversion between pts and cms by dividing by 28.45274. Always learning! :D

I forgot to reverse the reading direction so as not to cross. domain[#1:#2] for one and domain[#2:#1] for the other.

While pgfplots is indeed intimidating for sketching a few graphs, its fillbetween library is made for this. A \tikzfillbetween version can be used inside bare TikZ without a problem.
For comparison, I've also added a spath3 version where we

split the paths (internally) at their intersections and then
remove the outer parts so only the one below/above the to-be-filled area remains.

On the \fill path we use spath to create a new path that uses these remaining parts after another. (The fillbetween equivalent would be the sequence key.)
The keys weld, reverse and close (which is the equivalent of -- cycle) aren't really needed in this example since you only fill the path's area. But if you would draw this path or want to use it later it's always a good idea to create a proper path.
I opted to draw the area behind the paths (so that the line of the curves don't get covered). This also places the area behind the axis. If this is not wanted adjustment to the diagram are available.
Code
\documentclass [border = 5mm] {standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3, fillbetween, backgrounds}
% always useful:
  \newcommand*\tikzspathset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/spath}}
  \tikzspathset{.code=\tikzspathset{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (-3, 0) -- (5, 0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw [<->] (0, -1) -- (0, 4) node [right] {$y$};
\draw [name path = gx] plot [domain = -2:4]
  (\x, {0.25 * (\x - 1) * (\x  - 1) + 1.2}) node [above] {$g(x)$};
\draw [name path = fx] plot [domain = -1.1:2.5]
   (\x * 2, {0.8 * (\x + 1) * (\x - 1) * (\x - 2) + 1}) node [below right] {$f(x)$};
\draw [name intersections = {of = fx and gx}]
  (intersection-1) -- (intersection-1|-0,0) node [below] {$a$}
  (intersection-2) -- (intersection-2|-0,0) node [below] {$b$};

\tikzfillbetween[
  of=fx and gx,
  on layer=background,
  split,
  every even segment/.style=path only
]{red}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (-3, 0) -- (5, 0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw [<->] (0, -1) -- (0, 4) node [right] {$y$};
\draw [name path = gx] plot [domain = -2:4]
  (\x, {0.25 * (\x - 1) * (\x  - 1) + 1.2}) node [above] {$g(x)$};
\draw [name path = fx] plot [domain = -1.1:2.5]
   (\x * 2, {0.8 * (\x + 1) * (\x - 1) * (\x - 2) + 1}) node [below right] {$f(x)$};
\draw [name intersections = {of = fx and gx}]
  (intersection-1) -- (intersection-1|-0,0) node [below] {$a$}
  (intersection-2) -- (intersection-2|-0,0) node [below] {$b$};

\begin{scope}[
  on background layer,
  spath={
    split at intersections={fx}{gx},
    remove components={fx}{1,3},
    remove components={gx}{1,3},
  }
]
  \fill[red, spath={use=fx, use={gx, weld, reverse}, close}];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output

